# Creating 3D software C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have a project to do where I'm asked to create my own little 3D software in C++.

I'm not sure where to start from, I thought I might go with OpenGL 3.3, which i need to study first, and make it all accessible through a GUI ? 
Is it the right way to process ?

I've used 3D softwares like Blender, and all I want to do is something really basic :

- buttons to create primitive object
- move them
- rotate them
- scale them,
- maybe a bit of texturing and lighting

Comment: You can start from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out this tutorial: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20286/GLUI-Window-Template#_articleTop

or

You can look at mine I did for a school project.

https://github.com/sitting-duck/stuff/tree/master/School%20-%20Comp%20Sci/Computer%20Animation%20-%20Fall%202014/Assn1%20-%20Transformations/assn1%20redo/assn1

In this version I just use key bindings to initiate the transformations.  Will be easier than making a GUI, so I did that first to learn how to get the transformation code all working,

when you open it it's going to complain that it's missing libraries (like freeglut.lib) because I didn't upload them to github.  The reason I didn't upload them to github is because those libraries are going to keep being updated, so if I want to use this project I will just go redownload the latest versions.

You would have to go get those libraries and link them to your project.  You would also have to make sure the glew library is installed on your computer, so it will be a little more complicated than just copying my code to get it running, but at least you can look at mine and try to get an idea of what's going on.

I used the GLUI library for user interfaces, all the buttons and stuff usually, it's been a while since I've used this and there are probably other libraries that are better but I found GLUI to be pretty easy, I've also heard of ANTTweakBar being used for GUI stuff,

I have another project with more user interface stuff, but I'll have to find it and go upload it,

hopefully I gave you enough hints to where you can get up and running, you can see in my code what libraries I am using and go to the library websites to learn how to install them, link them to the project etc.

Here's some keywords, glew, glut, freeglut, glui, ANTTweakbar go look up those things,

also, you won't need to use Blender to make a model for your program, OpenGL already has some primitives built in that you can use to test out your transforms on.

probably with your current state of knowledge you won't be able to run and compile my project and unfortunately I did not post any instructions on my github :( but an example I'm sure will help you and when I finish some other work today I will go post installation instructions on there.

I made this using VisualStudio 2013 on Windows 8.1. You may need to use older versions of the glew and glut libraries if you are using older version of VisualStudio,

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , i'll get started with openGL and see where it leads me :D

Comment: Was the tutorial useful?